# django - manual initial migrate getting raw sql scripts

Tags: django

When initially setting up Django you run the following command -

`manage.py migrate`

Which will then output the following (as an example):

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, rest_framework, rest_framework_swagger, messages
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Is there a way to get the raw SQL that it's loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes run: [`manage.py sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate-app-label-migrationname).

Comment: I think this isn't 100% correct.  I can't simply run `python manage.py sqlmigrate` because it needs conditions.  What I'm saying is that I haven't even done a migration yet.  I want to get the raw sql that's actually creating the initial auth tables.

Comment: Yes, you get the sql from sqlmigrate.

Comment: ok I'm on a fresh project as in nothing has been put into the database.  I have no managed models (legacy db).  I run `manage.py sqlmigrate` and get `error: too few arguments`.  I can do the `manage.py migrate` which generates the tables in the db but it does not create a `migrations folder`.  I'm not seeing anywhere in the doc how to get the scripts.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it would migrate would create a migrations folder.  The migrations have already been generated for the built-in apps, you can see their names in your output. And I linked to the docs for sqlmigrate: it takes an app name and a migration name. So if you wanted to see the SQL for the initial auth migration you can do `manage.py sqlmigrate auth 0001_initial`.